# Draw image view with animation

Tags: android, android-canvas

I've create custom `ImageView` (extends from `ImageView`).
on the `onDraw` method I have a circle and I want to update the circle very often when `onSensorChanged` called.
what happens is that `canvas.drawCircle()` called with different values each time (I call invalidate when sensor change)
and I can see the circle moving but the movement is not smooth enough. I think because it's running on the main thread.
I don't have accesses to `surfaceHolder` from the image.
is there a way to make it run more smoothly?

```
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
canvas.drawRoundRect(mainRectangle, 20f, 20f, rectanglePaint);
canvas.drawRoundRect(validationRectangle, 20f, 20f, rectanglePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(circleXLocation, circleYLocation, circleRadios, circlePaint);
  }
```

the circle is moving with the change of `circleXLocation` and `circleXLocation`

Comment: how often does sensor change?

Comment: when   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) been called I'm not sure what the accurate number but very fast.

Comment: whats your onDraw look like?